# Python-devel yum install error

Tags: python, centos, yum

Installation of python-devel fails with attached message

Configuration is as follows:
 - CentOS 7.2 
 - Python 2.7 Installed

1. I re-ran with yum load as suggested in output and it failed with same message.
2. yum info python ==> Installed package python 2.7.5 34.el7
3. yum info python-devel ==> NOT installed. Available 2.7.5 48.el7
4. yum deplist python-devel ==> dependency on python2.7.5-48.el7
5. Tried to install Python2.7.5-48.el7 wih "yum update python" and it fails with same error message as python-devel install.

Sudhir

```
yum install -y python-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirrors.sonic.net
* epel: ftp.linux.ncsu.edu
* extras: mirror.cogentco.com
* updates: www.gtlib.gatech.edu
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-devel.x86_64 0:2.7.5-48.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python(x86-64) = 2.7.5-48.el7 for package: python-devel-2.7.5-48.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python.x86_64 0:2.7.5-34.el7 will be updated
---> Package python.x86_64 0:2.7.5-48.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: python-libs(x86-64) = 2.7.5-48.el7 for package: python-2.7.5-48.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-libs.x86_64 0:2.7.5-34.el7 will be updated
---> Package python-libs.x86_64 0:2.7.5-48.el7 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved
```

## ================================================================================ Package                              Arch                           Version                               Repository                    Size

```
Installing:
python-devel                         x86_64                         2.7.5-48.el7                          base                         393 k
Updating for dependencies:
python                               x86_64                         2.7.5-48.el7                          base                          90 k
python-libs                          x86_64                         2.7.5-48.el7                          base                         5.6 M

Transaction Summary
==============================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package
Upgrade             ( 2 Dependent packages)

Total size: 6.1 M
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
ERROR with transaction check vs depsolve:
python(abi) = 2.6 is needed by (installed) python-argparse-1.2.1-2.1.el6.noarch
python(abi) = 2.6 is needed by (installed) redhat-upgrade-tool-1:0.7.22-3.el6.centos.noarch
** Found 5 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
epel-release-7-6.noarch is a duplicate with epel-release-7-5.noarch
grep-2.20-3.el6_7.1.x86_64 has missing requires of libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
python-argparse-1.2.1-2.1.el6.noarch has missing requires of python(abi) = ('0', '2.6', None)
1:redhat-upgrade-tool-0.7.22-3.el6.centos.noarch has missing requires of preupgrade-assistant >= ('0', '1.0.2', '4')
1:redhat-upgrade-tool-0.7.22-3.el6.centos.noarch has missing requires of python(abi) = ('0', '2.6', None)
Your transaction was saved, rerun it with:
yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx.2017-02-13.16-01.jUFBE4.yumtx
```

Comment: Did you rerun it as the error message suggests? Please give us proper clues instead of error dumps.

Comment: 1. I reran with yum load-transaction but it fails with same error message

Answer (score 3):

From the yum documentation, here's the safest way to handle each of your 5 errors:

First remove duplicates and resolve any errors after running this:

```
package-cleanup --cleandupes
```

If the above comes with a missing package-cleanup error, then run this first:

```
yum install yum-utils
```

Then address the other 4 errors with:

```
yum reinstall grep-*
```

where grep-* is the package name as shown in the error message. I abbreviated the rest of the grep version name with * in the command above.

Repeat the above command for the 3 other packages that were indicated as missing. If yum command gives you errors, then try this for just that one package:

```
rpm -ivh --force grep-*
```

Then finally re-run the yum command from the original error message.

At any point you want to clean up leftover mess, run this command:

```
yum clean all
package-cleanup --problems
```

And follow directions. For further reference, look up documentation with

```
man yum.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed packages python-argparse and redhat-upgrade-tool.

Then did a yum install python-devel and it succeed's this time. I am thinking there is a hard dependency for those 2 packages on older python 2.6.

Sudhir Nallagangu

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are on CentOS 7, but have CentOS 6 packages installed.

- python-argparse-1.2.1-2.1.el6.noarch
- redhat-upgrade-tool-1:0.7.22-3.el6.centos.noarch

Get a list of all installed el6 packages (`rpm -qa | grep el6`) and remove them or update them to their el7 equivalents.  You should be able remove argparse, since it's in the 2.7 standard library.